# Derive Eq and Show for type alias in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

I've the following type alias

```
data    Bindable  = Const Value 
                      | Variable Location
                    | Func Function
                    | Proc
              deriving (Eq, Show)                                   

type Function = Argument -> Store -> Value
```

but the compiler gives me an error

```
No instance for (Show Function)
arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
Possible fix:
add an instance declaration for (Show Function)
or use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
   so you can specify the instance context yourself
When deriving the instance for (Show Bindable)
```

Can I define Show & Eq for Function? If not then what would be the solution? Should I define Eq and Show to Argument, Store and Value?

Answer (score 6):

Type class instances may only be defined for "real" types, as defined by a `data` or `newtype` declaration.  A `type` declaration is a "fake" type—just an abbreviation for a longer type.

But that's just problem #1 in this case.  Problem #2 is that even if you do this...

```
newtype Function = Function (Argument -> Store -> Value)
```

...there might still be no truly useful `Show` instance for `Function`.  How do turn a function into a string?  There are two strategies.  First, the "just give up" strategy:

```
instance Show Function where
    show _ = "<some Function, no clue what it does>"
```

Second, the "canonical example" strategy, where you apply the `Function` to some canonical `Argument` and `Store` and show these together with the `Value` result:

```
instance Show Function where
    show (Function fn) = "Function: " 
                      ++ show defaultArgument 
                      ++ " -> " 
                      ++ show defaultStore
                      ++ " -> " 
                      ++ show (fn defaultArgument defaultStore)
```

The idea here is to display the `Function` as one particular argument/value mapping of it that might help you identify it more precisely than just using the same constant string for all of them.  Whether this helps or not depends on what your functions do.

But now we have problem #3: neither of these obeys the intent/contract of the `Show` and `Read` classes, which is that `read (show x)` is equivalent to `x`.  (People do often ignore this intent, however, just because they want to print *something* and `Show` is the quickest ticket.  So much that, as Thomas DuBuisson points out, there's a standard module `Text.Show.Functions` that implements the "just give up" strategy.)

As for the `Eq` class, the answer is that it's just impossible in general to compare two functions for equality.  (If I recall correctly, it's equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, but don't quote me on that.)  If your solution requires you to compare functions for equality, you need a new solution...

Comment: telling if two programs are existentially equivalent is trivially as hard as solving the halting problem.  You have to know if a function halts to know that it is equal!  Or, alternatively, `solveHalting f = (\y -> seq (f x) y) == id`.  We know `solveHalting` can not exist by Turing's proof, so one gets no such `Eq` instance for functions.

Comment: yeah I understand what you are saying about Show, it does make perefect sense to me. For Eq, the problem is that I've to make Bindable to derive Eq because I need it for Value and Location for other functions. I don't need it though for functions and procedures, but I've to make them Bindables too. Do you see my problem?

Comment: Maybe you can redefine `Function` to include a function name and compare that? Depends on your use cases.

Comment: @MikeHartl: the problem is: what does equality mean?  The strongest response is that `x == y` if and only if for all `f`, `f x == f y`. The problem with defining equality in terms of names is that even if you take care to never give the same name to two unequal functions, you still can't generally arrange for two equal functions to get the same name. The only way I can see to do it is if your functions are  "compiled" from some recipe type that can be compared for equality, and the recipe -> function translation preserves recipe equality. (Which is an excellent technique, I should add.)

Answer (score 5):

Just import `Text.Show.Functions`.  Your `type` is just an alias, the error message is saying it can't find an instance of Show for `(->)`, but an instance is available in that module.

```
Prelude> import Text.Show.Functions
Prelude Text.Show.Functions> show (+1)
"<function>"
```

Comment: Thomas thanks for the quick help! it solved the problem for Show. What should I import for Eq?

Comment: You'll have to write your own instance (defaulting to True or False depending on what you want). `instance Eq Function where _ == _ = True`