# Haskell deriving Show error

Tags: haskell, show, deriving

I did some research about Colored Petri Nets for a university assessment, and I need to implement them in Haskell. I used [this](http://community.haskell.org/~claus/publications/HCPN.pdf) document as a point of start.

When I am trying to import this module in Haskell:

```
module SimpleHCPN where

import Data.List
import System.Random

data Net marking = Net {trans :: [Transition marking]}
                   deriving (Show)
data Transition marking = Transition { name :: String
                                     , action :: marking -> [marking]
                                     }
                          deriving (Show)
```

I receive the following error:

```
SimpleHCPN.hs:11:37: error:
    * No instance for (Show (marking -> [marking]))
        arising from the second field of `Transition'
          (type `marking -> [marking]')
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    * When deriving the instance for (Show (Transition marking))
```

I'm still a newbie in Haskell, so a little bit of help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: More related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15823732/791604), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15015698/791604), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10551210/791604).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`action` is of type `marking -> [marking]` and there is no instance of typeclass `Show` for functions.

You can import `Text.Show.Functions` for an typeclass instance of `Show` for functions, but I don't know, if it shows something useful or only `"Function"` for any function.

Comment: If the domain is small, [Data.Universe.Instances.Show](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-reverse-instances-1.0/docs/src/Data-Universe-Instances-Show.html) is another alternative.